# Visual Studio - Create my own ASP MVC Project Template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

I was wondering if there was a way to create my own project template using Visual Studio 2010 for ASP MVC or if there are any updated templates out there. My reason is that whenever I create a new project now, I have to update all of the packages (Entity Framework, JQuery etc..)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the following two blog posts by Phil Haack:

- [Creating a Custom ASP.NET MVC Project Template](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/06/05/creating-a-custom-asp-net-mvc-project-template.aspx)
- [A Really Empty ASP.NET MVC 3 Project Template](http://haacked.com/archive/2012/01/11/a-really-empty-asp-net-mvc-3-project-template.aspx)